# Is MFC still alive?

Tags: c++, c, mfc

I am new to programming. I'd like to learn a new application programming language. I Googled and found the old MFC framework. I would like to ask: Is MFC still valuable?

I want to develop desktop applications. If not what should I choose to learn in depth?

Comment: MFC is long gone. I disliked its design even 15 years ago. Just pick a portable UI toolkit...

Comment: and this was posted three years ago ... FML

Answer (score 9):

If you want to develop desktop applications, then I'd recommend to avoid MFC and study [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) instead. Qt is quite powerful/flexible and using it won't lock you into single platform/OS.

Comment: Thank you,Can we use Qt for develop powerful applications(I mean Word,Excel even 3Ds Max)?

Comment: @unique: Yes, you can - you can create [pretty much anything you want](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Software_that_uses_Qt). If you have doubts, download Qt install or compile it and launch "qtdemo" application. It demonstrates abilities of the framework.

Answer (score 3):

First, you must have clear the **platform** where you want your applications to run; Windows? Linux? both?

In case you just care about **Windows**, MFC can be a good option if you want to do C++ native programming, which I suppose it's your case (otherwise, C# and .net could be a better way to start programming...)

MFC is a **mature framework** and once you get the basics, it will be as easy (or difficult) to use as any other library (e.g. Qt or TCL/Tk). IMHO.

Comment: I like Windows platform. but it is better if cross platform

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried to use to MFC for a small client application.

After struggling for two days with trivial things (like how to change the font on a button!!) I gave up.

I gave a quick look at [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) and [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) but (after having lost another couple of days), they seemed too compex for my task. Qt is probably the right way to go if you have time and/or the constraint to stay with a C++ framework.

It was not the case for me, so I decided to try [Tcl/Tk](http://tcl.tk/) to see what it had for me.

In its "[tclkit/starkit](http://equi4.com/starkit/)" incarnation it allows you to create standalone GUI application with native look and feel.  C/C++ code can be placed in a DLL that is embedded in the exe itself (no DLL hell, thanks!) and can be called directly from the Tcl script.

In two days work I almost finished the entire GUI with all the user interactions (enable/disable menaingful button, load listbox depending on other fields, ...) that would have taken weeks in MFC.

Tcl/Tk has its learning curve and may result unfamiliar to some but it repays many many times in productivity. Also, there are a lot of books, tutorials, examples, etc to learn from.

I would suggest you to give a look to see if it suits your need before going elswhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with the document-view (MDI or SDI) nature of MFC go for it. It's great if your worried about distribution becuase you dont need a hefty framework, just a couple of DLLs. Don't expect rapid development without considerable background knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in more modern C++ frameworks for Windows, consider using WTL and ATL instead of MFC.

Comment: I don't claim to be an expert but from what I've seen ATL is the bare minimum, WTL is a little bit more programmer-friendly and MFC is more complete. I would not call WTL and ATL "more modern" than MFC!

Comment: @Remo.D They may not be as comprehensive as MFC, but they are newer.  Of the Windows C++ programmers in my circles, all have disdain for MFC but like ATL+WTL.